# iPad3 HD Black Screen in Portrait Orientation

Tags: ipad, cocos2d-iphone, screen, portrait

I'm currently updating my game using XCode 4.3.1 and an iPad3.  WHen iPAD HD mode is selected, I get a black screen when I change the scene from the AppDelegate.

I'm using COCOS2d v1.0.1

My Game is portrait only mode, and I think I've tracked the problem down.

If you create a new project with the default HelloWorld Layer, it works on the iPad3 and it's simulator in HD.

However if you change the following code :-

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

...

#elif GAME_AUTOROTATION == kGameAutorotationUIViewController
//
// EAGLView will be rotated by the UIViewController
//
// Sample: Autorotate only in landscpe mode
//
// return YES for the supported orientations

//return ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape( interfaceOrientation ) );
return ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait ( interfaceOrientation ) );

//return  NO;

...
}
```

In RootViewController.m

You see a black screen for the iPad3 real device and simulator.  It works as expected on all devices, iPhone/iPod Touch, and iPad 1 and 2.

If I change the statement back to

return ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape( interfaceOrientation ) );

I get the Hello World rendered to the screen, but it is in landscape only on iPad3.

Has anyone else encountered this and have any suggestions for a fix?

The project is quite large to upgrade to the latest V1 Beta code.

Comment: Are you sure `GAME_AUTOROTATION`  is defined as equal to `kGameAutorotationUIViewController` ?

Answer (score 2):

since it too late to respond. It can help others

try this line of code at

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:


[director setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];
```

hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you, this indeed fixes the issue! Is there any explanation why this only happen on the new iPad too and what's happening in the background with this call?

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem to this is in the new xcode, when u upgrade to the XCODE 4.5 with the new

IOS 6.0 sdk, the project "supported interface orientation" feature gets unselected,

try to select them all if u want all of them to be available,

this will solve the issue,

no need to change in the app-delegate  or to use 
[director setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D]; since it might mess up the display.

hope this helps, based on what i faced personally.

Answer (score 0):

Just disable Retina for iPad3
[director enableRetinaDisplay:YES];

Later, you can upgrade you app for iPad3 by adding XXXXXx-ipadhd.png (ipad retina version of images) to your project.